# Informações no Titulo - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Eu tenho uma aplicação onde o usuário pode selecionar a empresa a ser trabalhada.
Quando ele selecionar, gostaria que essas informações fossem para o Título da aplicação... Isso é possível?

O atributo Title está na janela pai. Já este evento MouseDoubleClick está em um UserControl filho... Esta é minha duvida, como passar do filho para o Pai..

Por enquanto eu tenho esse TextBlock para poder adicionar a informação no titulo:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Titulo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Titulo:

```
private string _titulo;

    public string Titulo
    {
        get
        {
            return _titulo;
        }
        set
        {
            _titulo = value;
        }
    }
```

O que posso fazer aqui quando o usuário selecionar?

```
private void dataGridEmpresa_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

          --- AQUI! ---

    }
```

Depois da alteração:

```
<my:EscolherEmpresa TitleValue="{Binding Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Onde eu abro a UserControl:**

```
private void main_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F5){

            tbTitulo.Text = "ESCOLHER EMPRESA PARA TRABALHAR";

            MainMdiContainer.Children.Clear();
            MainMdiContainer.Children.Add(new MdiChild()
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(-10, -28, 0, 0),
                Width = this.Width - 20,
                Height = this.Height - 113,
                //WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized,
                Style = null,
                Content = new Telas.EscolherEmpresa()
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Onde está exactamente a sua dificuldade? Está em como construir o *binding* no *xaml*, na implementação da interface *INotifyPropertyChanged* na classe que tem a propriedade *Titulo* ou está em como extrair, da *Grid*, o campo *titulo* no método `dataGridEmpresa_MouseDoubleClick()`?

Comment: Não estou utilizando MVVM @ramaral, Queria apenas levar algumas informações de meu DataGrid para o titulo da aplicação..

Comment: OK, mas a informação continua a ser pouca. Você fala num *TextBlock*, quer que essa informação seja colocada nele ou no atributo *Title* da *Window*. Se for no atributo basta, depois de ter essa informação, fazer no método `dataGridEmpresa_MouseDoubleClick()` `this.Title = varialvelQueTem_a_Infromacao;`

Comment: Então, mas o atributo Title está na janela pai. Já este evento MouseDoubleClick está em um UserControl filho... Esta é minha duvida, como passar do filho para o Pai...

Comment: Na pergunta você não fala isso.

Comment: Desculpa @ramaral, eu alterei a perguta.

Answer (score 2):

Não testei mas julgo que isto faz o que pretende.

No *UserControl* declare uma *DependencyProperty*

```
public string TitleValue
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TitleValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TitleValue", typeof(string),
                                 typeof(UserControl1));//Nome da classe do UserControl
```

No *XAML* da *Window* ao incluir o *UserControl*:

```
<my:UserControl1 TitleValue="{Binding Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

No método `dataGridEmpresa_MouseDoubleClick()`:

```
private void dataGridEmpresa_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

   string title = //Obtenha o titulo
   TitleValue = title;
}
```

Comment: apareceu o meu UserControl inteiro la em cima no titulo no pequeno espaço. Fiz algo de errado? Postei a imagem de como ficou la em cima no post

Comment: Quando estou na tela principal (Window Pai), eu dou um F5 e abre o meu UserControl. Dai que eu consigo selecionar a empresa a ser escolhida..

Comment: Poste o código onde abre o *UserControl*.

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta...

Comment: Assim não é fácil ajudar, você não refere em lado algum que está a usar a uma *api* externa ao *WPF*. Julgo que seja a *WPF.MDI.DLL*. Eu nunca a utilizei por isso não posso ajudá-lo.

Comment: Estou utilizando sim essa DLL. Mas de qualquer forma eu agradeço então..